# Regex for all sort of name

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am using this regex for handling all sort of names:

```
String Regex_Name="^([A-Za-z]*|\\p{L})+([ ]*|[A-Za-z]*|[']*|\\p{L}*)+([\\s]?[A-Za-z]*)+[A-Za-z]$";
```

While running the code I am getting this error:

```
Unknown character property name {â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹L} near index 44
^[A-Za-z][[A-Za-z]*\p{â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹L}â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹*[,]?[ ]?[-]?[A-Za-z]+]+([ ]?[.]?[,]?[(]?[A-Za-z]+[)]?[-]?\p{â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹L}â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹â€‹*)+([,]?|[.]?)$
```

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: First: [Falsehoods programmers believe about names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/). Second: Looks like there are some unprintable character in the regex - maybe an encoding issue? Did you copy the regex from somewhere?

Comment: Nopes have  written the regex on my own. can you help me with this Regex main issue that I can debug is coming in \\p{L} statement.. Not sure what is wrong over here

Comment: If you wrote the regex please explain it. What is the purpose you have in mind of  each of the elements ? Knowing that, misconceptions and other mistakes are more easily identified.

Comment: What language is that? Java or one of its extensions such as Groovy or Kotlin?

Comment: It looks like some typo, are there any invisible chars inside `\p{L}` in your original code? The pattern is very fragile in fact, you should fix it like `String Regex_Name="^\\p{L}+(?:[\\s']+\\p{L}+)*$";`

Comment: Assuming this is Java, it might be worth including the whole code that leads to the `Pattern` instance creation as the problem could be there. At least I can tell you there's nothing really wrong with the regex we're reading (which might not be your actual regex as control-characters would likely be stripped when posting) : https://ideone.com/EBIFK7

Comment: @Aaron There are A LOT of wrong things about the regex. It is a classic catastrophic backtracking prone pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'll definitely take your word for it, I meant to say there was nothing that could explain OP's problem. Anyway he would do well to use your regex, which would likely have the side-effect of fixing his problem if it was due to control characters.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```java
String Regex_Name="^\\p{L}+(?:[’'-]\\p{L}+)*(?:\\s+\\p{L}+(?:[’'-]\\p{L}+)*)*$";
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/4hZhOS/1).

**The expression does not support shortened, abbreviated names, like `John G. Smith`.**

**Explanation**

```java
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \p{L}+                   any character of: letters (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [’'-]                    any character of: '’', ''', '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \p{L}+                   any character of: letters (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \p{L}+                   any character of: letters (1 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [’'-]                    any character of: '’', ''', '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \p{L}+                   any character of: letters (1 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```